# Executar javascript ao clicar na combobox

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma maneira de quando tiver com uma *combobox* aberta executar um script?

Comment: sim era isso que queria.

Comment: você pode usar o evento click para isto, http://jsfiddle.net/4fLb5bqo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O evento de `click` você pode implementar da seguinte forma:

```
document.getElementById("combobox").addEventListener("click", eventoClick);

function eventoClick() {
    alert("teste do onclick")
}
```

Existe também o evento de `change` que é quando for alternado as opções do combobox:

```
document.getElementById("combobox").addEventListener("change", eventoClick); 

function eventoChange(){
        alert("teste do change")
}
```

E também o `mouseover`:

```
document.getElementById("combobox").addEventListener("mouseover", eventoMouseOver);

function eventoMouseOver() {
    alert("teste do mouseover")
}
```

Segue o [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/rbop7xs8/2/)

Comment: Obrigado :), existe também  alguma maneira de quando passar por cima de option executar também outro script?

Comment: `$("select option").hover(function() {
 alert("ola");
 });` fiz assim mas não esta a dar.

Comment: Atualizei o post e o jsfiddle =D